# Ubuntu call curl to localhost www - 403 forbidden

Tags: laravel, curl

On Ubuntu I have website in PHP and Laravel. I have web api action:

```
http://myserverip/walletNotify/8
```

When I past above address in my browser on my machine (not server) action return correct result.
But when I want to call this address from server (myserverip) using curl:

```
curl http://myserverip/walletNotify/8
```

I get error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
<hr>
```

I call curl from user and from root user but in both cases result is the same.
This controller (walletNotify) is outside authentication.

Comment: So you need to post to the api with the api token.

Comment: Is this Get Request. If it's post request then you have to pass csrf token or create api in `api.php` inside route folder

Comment: Yes, this is GET request. But my controller is outside authentication. I'm logged out and when I past url to the browser it works. This is my router.php: $router->get('/walletNotify/{txid}', ['uses' => 'TransactionApi@walletNotify', 'as' => 'transactionapi.walletNotify']);